# Downloading dependencies from pom.xml with Aether

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, aether

I need to download all dependencies from a given pom.xml in my java programm. In Aether examples I can see only examples of resolving and downloading artifacts by maven coordinates, so I have to parse pom.xml, resolve constants in             `<version>` tag, handle exclusions and etc. by myself. Can Aether (or other tool) do it for me?

Comment: The tool is called Maven which do all that?

Comment: How can I use it inside java code?

Comment: [Try this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20parse%20xml%20in%20java). Please come back when [you have a more specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Parsing of pom.xml isn't the only problem. I mentioned about constants resolving and exclusions.

Comment: Why would you like to use that within code? If you would be more specific what you like to achieve you will get better and more accurate answers.

Comment: Because I can't be sure that maven installed on user's computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ShrinkWrap](https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver#resolution-of-artifacts-defined-in-pom-files) instead, which uses Aether itself underneath. Example:

```
Maven.resolver()
    .loadPomFromFile("/path/to/pom.xml")
    .importRuntimeDependencies()
    .resolve()
    .withTransitivity()
    .asFile();
```